# MVC3 validation failing when trying to add ajax post function

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, jquery, jquery-validate

I am having some troubles with validation using jquery to post a forms data to a controller.

This code works and validation happens fine if I dont use jquery to make the post.

```
<div id="window">
@using (Html.RequiredFieldsMessage()){}
@using (Html.BeginForm("","",FormMethod.Post,new{id="card-payment"}))
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "Please fix the errors below.")
    <div class="inputForm no-border">
        <div class="fr">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.DpsPaymentModel.CardHolderName)
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.DpsPaymentModel.CardHolderName)
            @Html.ValidationStyledMessageFor(model => model.DpsPaymentModel.CardHolderName, false)
          </div>
        <div class="fr">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.DpsPaymentModel.CardNumber)
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.DpsPaymentModel.CardNumber)
            @Html.ValidationStyledMessageFor(model => model.DpsPaymentModel.CardNumber, false)
        </div>
        <div class="fr">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.DpsPaymentModel.DateExpiry)
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.DpsPaymentModel.DateExpiry)
            @Html.ValidationStyledMessageFor(model => model.DpsPaymentModel.DateExpiry, false)
        </div>
        <div class="fr">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.DpsPaymentModel.Cvc2)
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.DpsPaymentModel.Cvc2)
            @Html.ValidationStyledMessageFor(model => model.DpsPaymentModel.Cvc2, false)
        </div>
        <div class="fr">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.DpsPaymentModel.Amount)
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.DpsPaymentModel.Amount)
            @Html.ValidationStyledMessageFor(model => model.DpsPaymentModel.Amount, false)
        </div>
        <div class="fr">
            <button type="submit" id="process-payment">Submit</button>
        </div>
    </div>

}
</div>
```

If I add this to my view. The validation is always returned as true. My html is not in a partial view its in the same view that loads the correct jquery validation scripts.

```
  $("#process-payment").click(function () {
            event.preventDefault();
            var form = $("#card-payment");
            $.validator.unobtrusive.parse(form);
            if (form.validate()) {
                console.log("valid");
                $.ajax({
                    url: '/payment/processcardpayment',
                    type: "POST",
                    data: form.serialize(),
                    success: function (data) {
                        console.log(data);

                    },
                    error: function (jqXhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                        alert("Error '" + jqXhr.status + "' (textStatus: '" + textStatus + "', errorThrown: '" + errorThrown + "')");
                    },
                    complete: function () {
                        //       $("#ProgressDialog").dialog("close");
                    }
                });
            } else {
                console.log("invalid");
            }

        });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are calling `event.preventDefault();` in your click handler but there's no `event` variable defined anywhere so I guess you get a javascipt error. Have you looked at the console of your javascript debugging tool by the way?

Maybe you meant your click handler to take this as argument:

```
$("#process-payment").click(function (evt) {
    evt.preventDefault();
    ...
});
```

But I'd actually recommend you subscribing to the submit event of the form instead of the click handler of a submit button. This will for example account for the case when the user presses Enter when inside some input field to submit the form instead of pressing on the submit button.

Also the correct method to verify if a form is valid is `form.valid()` and not `form.validate()` as in your example, In addition to that you don't need to call `$.validator.unobtrusive.parse` unless you are updating the DOM with a new form in say for example an AJAX call. In this case you should call this inside the success callback once you have replaced the DOM with the new form elements in order to parse the new unobtrusive validation rules.

So:

```
$('#card-payment').submit(function(evt) {
    evt.preventDefault();
    var form = $(this);
    if (form.valid()) {
        $.ajax({
            url: this.action,
            type: this.method,
            data: form.serialize(),
            success: function (result) {
                console.log(result);
            },
            error: function (jqXhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert("Error '" + jqXhr.status + "' (textStatus: '" + textStatus + "', errorThrown: '" + errorThrown + "')");
            },
            complete: function () {
                // $("#ProgressDialog").dialog("close");
            }
        });
    } else {
        console.log("invalid");
    }
});
```